# When writing an IntelliJ Plugin in Java I get ClassNotFoundException but the class exists

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

There are similar question in SO, but I'm sure this is different.

I'm developing an IntelliJ Idea Plugin, and the issue is with a class that is under IDE's classpath, I mean that the class is loaded with the IDE application itself.

Please look at these screenshots:

I can get the class by `.javaClass` in kotlin or `.getClass()` in java.

[image: fig 1]

When accessing the class (no luck)

[image: fig 2]

Getting class by reflection (no luck)

[image: fig 3]

The code: [github reference](https://github.com/MohammadMD1383/Actionable/blob/f45cda60f4f00e2aa329790731fe7d63658f1472/src/main/java/ir/mmd/intellijDev/Actionable/selection/Actions.kt#L102)

```kotlin
class SelectLiteralElementUnderCaretAction : SelectTextUnderCaretAction() {
    private fun rawSelectionRange(caret: Caret) = caret.util.run {
        if (!moveUntilReached("\"'`", "\n", BACKWARD)) return@run null
        val startCandidateOffset = prevCharOffset
        val startCandidateChar = prevChar!!
        val backwardDistance = (caret.offset - startCandidateOffset).absoluteValue
        reset()
        
        if (!moveUntilReached("\"'`", "\n", FORWARD)) return@run null
        val endCandidateOffset = nextCharOffset
        val endCandidateChar = nextChar!!
        val forwardDistance = (caret.offset - endCandidateOffset).absoluteValue
        reset()
        
        if (startCandidateChar == endCandidateChar)
            return@run startCandidateOffset..endCandidateOffset + 1
        
        if (backwardDistance < forwardDistance) {
            if (!moveUntilReached(startCandidateChar.toString(), "\n", FORWARD)) return@run null
            return@run startCandidateOffset..nextCharOffset + 1
        }
        
        if (backwardDistance > forwardDistance) {
            if (!moveUntilReached(endCandidateChar.toString(), "\n", BACKWARD)) return@run null
            return@run prevCharOffset..endCandidateOffset + 1
        }
        
        return@run null
    }
    
    private fun shrinkSelection(caret: Caret): IntRange? {
        val text = caret.selectedText!!
        val first = text.first()
        val last = text.last()
        
        if (first == last && first in "`'\"") {
            val oldStart = caret.selectionStart
            val start = text.indexOfFirst { it != first }
            val end = text.indexOfLast { it != last }
            
            return (oldStart + start)..(oldStart + end + 1)
        }
        
        return null
    }
    
    override fun getSelectionRange(caret: Caret, psiFile: PsiFile): IntRange? {
        if (caret.hasSelection())
            shrinkSelection(caret)?.let { return it }
        
        val element = psiFile.elementAt(caret)
        
        return when (psiFile.fileType.name.lowercase()) {
            "java" -> element?.parentOfType<PsiLiteralExpression>(true)?.textRange?.intRange
            
            "kotlin" -> element?.parentOfType<KtStringTemplateExpression>(true)?.textRange?.intRange // issue is here
            
            "javascript",
            "typescript" -> element?.parentOfTypes(
                JSStringTemplateExpression::class,
                JSLiteralExpression::class,
                withSelf = true
            )?.textRange?.intRange
            
            "go" -> element?.parentOfType<GoStringLiteral>()?.textRange?.intRange
            
            else -> rawSelectionRange(caret)
        }
    }
}
```

### What I Tried

I tried reflection and it didn't help.

I used ide-scripting-console to be sure that this type exists at runtime and existed

I also have the dependency on Kotlin plugin

[image]

Comment: As a guess: The class may have failed to initialize (exception in static initializer blocks or static field initialization). I'd check for the earliest `ClassNotFoundException` I could and look for a chained exception. That said, without the class in question's code we can't confirm that.

Comment: Have you checked if your desired class is public/private/package? Otherwise if you see the class exists during development but not during runtime, the classpath at runtime may need fixing. Since you are developing a plugin, maybe you need to declare somewhere the other package is required.

Comment: The best place to ask such questions would be https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development.

Comment: This is most likely something to do with ClassLoaders.  If you aren't in the correct class loader when querying for the class then it won't be seen.  AND Intellij will have to create a separate ClassLoader for your plugin so that it could unload your plugin as you are developing it.  Otherwise it'd load it once and never unload it because that's how ClassLoaders work.  That would hamper coding quite a bit if you have to quite IJ every time you want to reload your plugin.  I think the other forum would be more helpful, but I'd be looking at what ClassLoader I was using.

Comment: @Rogue I edited my question and provided the source code, but that shouldn't be related to constructor because I just use the class as a generic parameter

Comment: @Queeg The class is public, and I have the dependency on kotlin plugin, see the the latest version of the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue. thanks to @Queeg and @chubbsondubs for their comments.

I added the dependency to kotlin plugin in `plugin.xml` like below:

```xml
<depends>org.jetbrains.kotlin</depends>
```

and also changed the plugin ids in `build.gradle` as follows *(but I don't  think that the problem was actually from here)*:

```kotlin
plugins.add("com.intellij.java")
plugins.add("org.jetbrains.kotlin")
```

which previously was:

```kotlin
plugins.add("java")
plugins.add("Kotlin")
```